# Count total sum of the same product name in my ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

How do I count total amount  of cars of the same car name by a group using LINQ (using Query or method syntax)..? My table name "Cars" looks like following:

```
CarId   CarName Color   Status
1      Volvo    Red      2 
2      Toyota   Black    1
3      Volvo    White    5
4      Ford     Blue     3
5      Toyota   Silver   5
```

I want result like this (Name of the Car and summery of Status):

```
Volvo   7
Toyota  6
Ford    3
```

In this Result I have 7 Volovs, 6 Toyotas and 3 Fords. 
How should I form it to get the correct Result that I'am looking for?
I tried

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetSumOfCars()
        {
            using (context)
            {
                return (PartialView("_CarList", await context.Cars.GroupBy(m =>m.CarName).Count????.ToListAsync()));
            }

        }
```

or LINQ (using query syntax)

```
var _Results = from Cars in ???
        Count(Status)
                groupedby CarName
                select Status;
```

But givs me wrong Result.
I would be grateful if you guys would help me.

Comment: `context.Cars.GroupBy(x => x.CarName).Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Number = x.Count() });`

Comment: But if you using this in a partial view, you will want to create a view model with those 2 properties (and it will be `.Select(x => new yourViewModel {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your response, but I don't get it if I have PartialView.. I have now my Viewmodel like this, public class CarSummeryViewModel
    {
       public string CarName { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }

    }

Comment: So it will be `context.Cars.GroupBy(x => x.CarName).Select(x => new CarSummeryViewModel  { CarName = x.Key, Status = x.Count() });` and then in your `_CarList.cshtml` partial you have `@model IEnumerable<CarSummeryViewModel>` and use a `@foreach(var car in Model)` to display the items. (but `Total` seems a more appropriate property name than `Status`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke This gave me appierence of CarName, I mean Volvo = 2, Toyota = 2, Ford   =1. How many times they appiere. But I want summery of Status of Volvo cars, Toyota..and so no....

Comment: What do you mean summary of Status? Do you mean you want the total? - in which case it would be `Status = x.Sum(y => y.Status)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Now it's fine. this person who called "dasblinkenlight"  did it as x.Sum(c => c.Status) and working fine. I real want to thank you all of you guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group by section of your query is correct.

Selecting count from the group usually comes with an anonymous class:

```
return PartialView(
    "_CarList",
    await context.Cars
        .GroupBy(m =>m.CarName)
        .Select(g => new { CarName = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(c => c.Status) })
        .ToListAsync()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from car in context.Cars 
group car by new { car.CarName } into carGrouping
select new {
  Name=carGrouping.Key,
  Count = carGrouping.Count()
};
```